# how to reset the keydown function using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to reset the keydown function using jquery?

For example, I two ul list of data and each have a document.keydown method to controll the scrolling either left or right.

```
            $(document.keydown(function(e1)
            {
                // ul list 1 - insert data

               if(e.which == leftArrowKey1)
               {
                       // scroll left

               }else if(e.which == rightArrowKey1 || e.which == spacebarKey1)

                      // scroll right                                               
               }
            });
            $(document.keydown(function(e2)
            {
                  // ul list 2 - insert data

               if(e2.which == leftArrowKey2)
               {
                  // scroll left

               }else if(e2.which == rightArrowKey2 || e2.which == spacebarKey2)

                  // scroll right                     
               }
            });
```

## THe Problem

The problem is after I scroll either left or right of the first list, I can scroll the other list even after I insert data into it. For example, I insert data into list A, and can successfully scroll either left or right. Now I insert data into list B, I can not scroll either left or right of list B and it continues to scroll list A.

Comment: add a variable to define the program state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read up on the [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) function a bit. The example on that page will work for you.

Also, you have a small problem with your code,

```
$(document.keydown(e1)
{
     // Your code
});
```

Should be

```
$(document).keydown(function(e1)
{
     // Your code
});
```

### Edit:

The easiest way to handle both lists at the same time is give them a class, lets say `scrollable`. One thing you will have to do is add a `tabindex` attribute to your `ul` elements so they are focusable: `<ul class="scrollable" tabindex="1">`. You'll have to click on the list you want to scroll before the `keydown` event will fire.

**Note: each `ul` will need a unique tabindex (make the 2nd list's `tabindex=2`)**

Now the jQuery is quite simple:

```
$('ul.scrollable').keydown(function(event)) {
    // Your scrolling code
}
```

Comment: correct, in my code I have the function added and forgot to added in the example, How can I get the keydown function to work between two list?

Comment: Do you need to scroll the lists separately? Or does one push of the left button scroll them both at the same time?

Comment: I need to scroll the list separately